# SQL - where MIN date is exactly 7 days ago

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, min

I need to select only the lines where MIN date is 7 days ago.
I have Customers with invoices, the invoices have due dates. I can select MIN due date of these invoices per Customer. I am now stuck as I cannot select only the Customers who are exactly 7 days overdue with their oldest invoice.

This is what I have:

```
select
 customerID,
 MIN(dueDate) as min_due_date
 from invoices
 where (invoiceStatus NOT IN ('PaidPosted','Cancelled'))
 and (entity = 'HQ')
 group by (customerID)
```

I tried adding:

```
and min_due_date = dateadd(day, -7, SYSDATE())
```

This does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I was browsing the site for more than an hour now with no luck in finding similar case.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is the database brand = MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `having` clause to filter the minimum date:

```
select customerID, min(dueDate) as min_due_date
from invoices
where invoiceStatus not in ('PaidPosted', 'Cancelled') and
      entity = 'HQ'
group by customerID
having min(duedate) = current_date - interval '7 day';
```

Note that date functions are highly database specific.  The above is standard SQL, but the exact syntax depends on the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Gordon, you put me on the right track!
This is what eventually did the trick:

```
select customerID, min(dueDate) as min_due_date
from invoices
where invoiceStatus not in ('PaidPosted', 'Cancelled') and
      entity = 'HQ'
having MIN(dueDate) = trunc(sysdate) -7
group by customerID
```

Comment: There is no `trunc()` function in MySql. Set the correct tag in your question.